# Is there a software tool or web service to detect problems in speech recordings?

Tags: audio, audio-processing

I am looking for a software/library or a web service/API that can detect problems in short samples of recordings of speech.

For example echo, clipping, pop, background noise...

Do you know of any tool that detects at least some of those?

Comment: try googling “audio cleanup “.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now started to build up my own tool collection and publish it as an API.

https://www.tinydrop.io/documentation/

The first feature is clipping detection, next up will be wind, ambient noise and reverb detection.